# Material UI makeStyles override class properties in it when it is under other class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using NavLink in react-router-dom with activeClassName. In that NavLink I have ListItems from material ui which has some css. I want to change that css if that particular NavLink has active class assigned.

I know I can't reference abc as "& abc" because makeStyle will create dynamic name for that. That's where I am stuck. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

This is the code I am trying:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  abc: {
    color: "white",
  },
  xyz: {
    "& abc": {
       color: "red"
    }
  }
}
```

```
<List>
    {pages.map((key) => {
        let Component = key.icon;
        return (
            <NavLink
                activeClassName={classes.xyz}
                to={key.to}
                onClick={() => setActive(key.to)}
            >
                <ListItem className={classes.abc}>
                    <ListItemIcon className={classes.abc}>
                      <Component />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                      primary={key.label}
                      className="navText"
                    ></ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            </NavLink>
       );
})}
</List>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using $ solved my problem.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  abc: {
    color: "white",
  },
  xyz: {
    "& $abc": {
       color: "red"
    }
  }
}
```

Got this solution from documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`abc` is class so you need to add `.`

```
  xyz: {
    "& .abc": {
       color: "red"
    }
  }
```

And change `className={classes.abc}` inside `xyz` to `className="abc"`

Comment: but material ui renames this classname to something like this r8? ```mui-abc-uuid```?

Comment: Just change `className={classes.abc}` to `className="abc"`

Comment: But then color: white won't apply R8? Because that is initial prop